# Meaning of Speed and Duplex pin in the IC

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, clock, ethernet, phy

In this - [Link](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/LAN9353) of the datasheet, can someone tell me what is the meaning/purpose of the DUPLEX Pin and the SPEED pin.

Unable to understand what it actually does and what does it indicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These signals are generated by an external physical layer controller (the PHY) and tell the MAC how fast and what duplex the Ethernet link is in:

[image]

Comment: But in usual and general PHY Transceivers, these DUPLEX and SPEED pins are not a part of the MII/RMII interface, right?

Comment: @Newbie I don’t see them in the spec, and I did a quick survey of the microchip phys to see if they used them and the closest I get is that the phy has those same inputs as bootstrap configs… it’s weird for sure, especially since the value can be overridden by the more common management registers.

Comment: Oh, OK. Thank you. But these DUPLEX and SPEED signals are usually common in PHYs, right? But Microchip PHYs don't have it right?

Comment: I would say the opposite, they’re not common at all, hopefully someone else who’s made lots of Ethernet devices can give some more input.